# How to know for which element error 'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' is thrown?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

When I run Selenium tests, tests fail intermittently with error:

```
 'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with'
```

But for which element this is the error, is not mentioned in the error log. Is there any way, we can determine that for which element 'Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with' error is thrown?

Here is a stacktrace:

```
- Manage tab search: should test search by valid entire description within label: error - Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with ; ["[remote server] file:///C:/Temp/webdriver-profile20130701-4012-14mgqix/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:7736:in `fxdriver.preconditions.visible'", "[remote server] file:///C:/Temp/webdriver-profile20130701-4012-14mgqix/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10437:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.checkPreconditions_'", "[remote server] file:///C:/Temp/webdriver-profile20130701-4012-14mgqix/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10456:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'", "[remote server] file:///C:/Temp/webdriver-profile20130701-4012-14mgqix/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10461:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'", "[remote server] file:///C:/Temp/webdriver-profile20130701-4012-14mgqix/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10401:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/<'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:51:in `assert_ok'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:15:in `initialize'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:59:in `create_response'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:66:in `request'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:40:in `call'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:629:in `raw_execute'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:607:in `execute'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:364:in `clickElement'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.33.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb:54:in `click'", "C:/Temp/d20130701-2976-tv6kuq/lib/backjax_manage_search_helper.rb:147:in `select_label'", "./tests/backjax_manage_search_by_description.rb:36:in `test_search_by_valid_entire_description_within_label'", "./tests/backjax_manage_search_by_description.rb:85:in `BackjaxManageSearchTest'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1258:in `__send__'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1258:in `run'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-reporters-0.14.20/lib/minitest/reporters.rb:62:in `run_with_hooks'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:105:in `run'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:153:in `call'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:153:in `recursively_run_setup_and_teardown'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:155:in `recursively_run_setup_and_teardown'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:139:in `run_setup_and_teardown'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/scope-0.2.4/lib/scope.rb:105:in `run'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:933:in `_run_suite'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:926:in `map'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:926:in `_run_suite'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-reporters-0.14.20/lib/minitest/reporter_runner.rb:45:in `_run_suite'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/parallel_each.rb:71:in `_run_suites'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/parallel_each.rb:70:in `map'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/parallel_each.rb:70:in `_run_suites'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-reporters-0.14.20/lib/minitest/reporter_runner.rb:37:in `_run_suites'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:877:in `_run_anything'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1085:in `run_tests'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-reporters-0.14.20/lib/minitest/reporter_runner.rb:30:in `run_tests'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1072:in `send'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1072:in `_run'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1071:in `each'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1071:in `_run'", "C:/jruby-1.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/shared/gems/minitest-4.7.5/lib/minitest/unit.rb:1059:in `run'", "./tests/backjax_manage_search_by_description.rb:98:in `(root)'"]
```

Comment: Yes, but there is no information for which element the error is thrown.

Comment: Updated question with stacktrace.

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question and thanks for helping!